# Android: modify EditText during typing in

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to modify in the real time what user is typing in into EditText.
There is no difference which modification it will be (eg. i want to remove every "i" letter which has been typed in).
In JavaSE I can do this using DocumentFilter which is attachet to Document of each JTextField, but i can't figured out how to do it in Android.

Another small question: do emulator of Android in eclipse respect setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS)? I ask because in my case on the very beginning it seems to be worked, but after couple of letters suggestions appear.
//---------------SOLUTION BASED ON Naveen Kumar's ANSWER----------------//
This code reacts if user will press enter (i know that there can be reaction which compares key code, but in my case this is better):

```
searchInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {
            if (s.toString().contains("\n"))
            {
                searchInput.setText(s.toString().replace("\n", ""));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
        {}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
            if (!s.toString().contains("\n"))
            {
               // DO SOMETHING
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes writting TextWatcher listener to the Edittext..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi i found solution with you desired logic you will try this logic and it will be a example and tell me how it's working....

Text watcher is the function to listen the text changing in the Edit text field in android...use this below code...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                System.out.println(s);
                if(s.length()>0)
                {
                    String newString = s.toString();
                    if(newString.contains("i")) {
                        String re = newString.replace("i", "");
                        text.setText(re);
                        text.setSelection(re.length());
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: COMMENT TO SOLUTION: This approach seems to be proper for me. Although i had to modify afterTextChanged because real purpose of this question is to react on pressing ENTER (but not by using key listener but by analyze of content of String - look for full solution in my question).

Answer (score 1):

You can add one observer to the editText. In this way, while the text in changing, you can modify the text. But anyway, this effect/event could be weird for the user. Imagine that you are typing and at the same time, some of the letter dissapear.

```
EditText searchTo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.medittext);
searchTo.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        do_Something_Here();
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        or_maybe_do_Something_here();
    } 
});
```

About the emulato, could be happen, sometime I've had some issues also with the keyboard of the emulator...anyway, are you using still the native emulator? You should star to use this one: are awesome and faster faster!

[Genymotion emulator](http://www.genymotion.com/)

Thinking about your question...maybe you should apply the filter of characters when the user end to type, i mean, when the edit text loss the focus...could be a better solution.

To detect when the edittext loses the focus:

```
txtEdit.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(!hasFocus)
           //do job here owhen Edittext lose focus 
    }
});
```

If it is helpful, vote me ;)

Comment: When you will edit s in afterTextChanged() you will cause another call of listener. In description of 'onTextChanged' is clearly remarked that changing of 's' is an error. I tried genny, but afaik i cant configure there custom parameters of smartphone. Am i right?

Comment: Maybe you can use a flag for detect when the edittext is used for the user or for your method to delete the characters. About the parameters  on the emulator, I am not sure if you can or not set that configuration that you wish. Sorry.